# Filtering column data in SQL Server 2008 R2 Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, filtering, replication, transactional-replication

Is it possible to filter the data content of columns published in standard transactional replication of a SQL Server 2008 R2 database?

If I filter the columns themselves, they vanish entirely in the subscriber tables.  I want the columns to exist, but be empty regardless of whether there is data in that column on the publisher side.

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by adding the columns using a post-snapshot script.  Have a look at [Execute Scripts Before and After the Snapshot Is Applied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152525.aspx).

Comment: I like Brandon's idea, publish without columns, then in post snapshot script, add them if they don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, but you could hack the subscriber procedures to do that.